# Make UISwitch border width smaller

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

Hello I am trying to make `UISwitch` `borderWidth` smaller, but it doesn't look correct.

All I did is
`layer.borderWidth = 0.5`

[image: It looks like there is two layers. The border color is suppose to be gray, but for some reason black shows?]

Answer (score 2):

instead of using storyboard try to customise switch programmatically . try using following code as if you change one parameter must adjust radius of switch too. Hope it helps

```
OnOffSwitch.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
OnOffSwitch.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0;
```

[image]

```
OnOffSwitch.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
OnOffSwitch.layer.cornerRadius = 17.0;
```

[image]